# Multi-level folding and Search Everything features from Sublime Text Editor alternatives on VIM?

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

Multi-level folding enables you to fold everything at a level by pressing a hotkey. It is being useful to get an overview of your code, like this one: http://o7.no/N72vMK

Go to anything is pressing Alt+P. This enables you to quickly go to any file typing part of it's name ('teshtm' would jump to 'test.html') and even to any function in your file.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Sublime text much (tried it only for a short time) but "multi-level folding" you can achieve just by folding to a certain `foldlevel` in Vim.

As far as the other (go to file) thing, similarly, you can achieve it by just using `gf` function and for example CtrlP plugin. The idea behind CtrlP originated from Textmate from Mac. I don't personally use it, but some people like the principle and swear by it ... from what I've seen it is implemented very nicely for those that like that kind of navigation.

Comment: If you don’t like the speed of CtrlP (or’ve looked at its source code and are now unsure how *that* can work) there is Command-T plugin with just the same idea, but implemented in ruby and C with a bit of VimL.

Comment: @Idigas It is the comment for the OP. From what I’ve seen I am fine with CtrlP speed, but I did not use it on large projects and sometimes heard the complains. What I do know is that CtrlP source code uses lots of globals, has things that can be written better, has weird coding style and pushes some settings in modelines that I consider personal. I saw five other file listing plugins’ source code when making aurum able to use them for prompting user, this appeared to be the worst (though supporting code is on the second place if you consider amount of lines I had to add after tlib#input#List).

Answer (score 3):

**multi-level folding**

Use `zM` and `zR` to close and open all the folds in the current buffer. That's the equivalent of ST2's "Fold all" and "Unfold All".

Use `: set foldlevel=x` to close everything after level `x`. `:set fdl=0` would close everything while `:set fdl=999` would open everything. That's the equivalent of "Fold Level x".

See `:help fold.txt` and `:help 'foldlevel'`.

As for everything, you can create custom mappings for all of that if you think that's too much typing. Notice however that you can use `zm` and `zr` to increment and decrement the foldlevel.

**Alt+P (Ctrl+P on Linux)**

I love the aforementioned [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) which I use for opening files, navigating buffers, navigating tags, etc. It's very well designed and intuitive. Some people complain about its lack of speed in large projects… my projects are relatively small so I can't really comment on this.

It has a rather big advantage over ST2's implementation: file navigation is not restricted to the current project. If you open a single file in ST2, you can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (on Linux) to open a nearby file: you must open a folder or create a project. or use the regular "Open File…" UI. "Go to anything" is a bit of a stretch, here.

Here is how I use CtrlP:

```
,ffo<CR> open foo.txt
,bba<CR> jump to buffer bar.txt
,tba<CR> jump to function baz() in curent buffer
,Tfo<CR> jump to function foo() in project
```

There are actually many plugins exploring the same idea: [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025), [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890), [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984), etc. Be sure to try all of them before you jump on the `{pluginname}` bandwagon.

Keep in mind that Vim's default file navigation is quite nice in its own right: `:e filename`, `:e fi<Tab>`, `:e *na<Tab>`…

Comment: Nicely explained! Afraid I'm just too lazy for an explanation of this depth). This should be the accepted answer.